# jquery on canvas - event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, canvas

I tried to understand how to make keypress event work with canvas using jquery (and addEventListener method). I found that keypress event works fine with:

```
document.onkeypress = checkKey;
```

where checkKey is function. But i really want to know why that works while other methods like:

- document.addEventListener("keypress", function() { checkKey(); }); , or
- $("canvas").keypress( function() { checkKey(); });

are not working.
I saw here on stackoverflow some ideas to add attribute - `tabindex`, but why is that the necessary? Is there any other possibilities?

Comment: You shouldn't bundle the callback function inside another anonymous function. e.g. `document.addEventListener("keypress", checkKey);`

Comment: @obscure Why exactly anonymous function should not be used? Than what to do when i want to pass argument when event occured? Beside that what you wrote works with addEventListener. Still not working with jquery though :(.

Comment: Well it ain't generally bad - it depends on the use-case of course. But I'm afraid we have too little information to really help you. I'd recommend spicing up your question with a concrete code example. Without more context it's a bit hard to answer your question.

Comment: @obscure sure, I think there is not really much to add, but i will try. I just want to understand some javascript + jquery methodology of working. I have canvas, and i want to make some stuff with use of keyboard keys. I've alrady used mouse events, like click and dblclick, and they works fine with lines like: `canvas.dblclick( function() { ... }`. Now i want to try do something with keypress. The problem is that in documentation i saw that events for keyboard works on input elements, so i assume that there may be problem with make it works on divs (canvas in that situation)?

Comment: As much as i tried i cannot make it working. I know that anonymous functions are really must-have if i want to pass some arguments to other functions, I;m not really sure why with `addEventListener` when not using anonymous function i made it working. Also i really want to make it works with jquery, or if it's not possible i want to know that ;d. Of course if it would be better to add more code i will do that. I just wanted to add that what i;m looking for is not really an answer to specific problem. I'm just curious.

Comment: So to sum up i made it like you wrote:
`document.addEventListener("keypress", checkKey);`
and it works - so first question is - why it works now, but with anonymous function not?
- second question is - is it possible to make it works with jquery? I tried things like `canvas.keypress(checkKey);`, or `&("document").on("keypress", checkKey);`, nothing works :(
- third question - why it was working better (easier in my opinion) with mouse event like click? I've made that works with `canvas.dblclick(function() { })`,why here anonymous function wasn't problem and with eventListener it already is